# bash find treating * as *

Tags: bash, escaping, special-characters

```
#!/bin/bash
read nameArg
find -name "$nameArg"
```

With this code when I input for example *.txt it will give me all the files that ends on txt, but I want only the specific one which name is *.txt. How to make bash treating * as * ?

Straight in terminal I know I should do:

```
find -name "\*.txt"
```

How to make it work in script ? Note there will not always be * in input.

Comment: Ouch, wrong problem to solve. The real problem is creating files with those names.

Comment: True true, but one does not always have control of user/client/grandparent submitted files :)

Comment: Only said that cuz the OP hints that this will be an ongoing issue. Would be worthwhile to come up with ways to prevent it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could escape the * on the fly like this:

```
find -name "${nameArg//\*/\\*}"
```

If, as Ed suggests, you might want a more general solution, you could use printf's %q format:

```
nameArg=$(printf '%q' "$nameArg")
```

or if your printf supports it:

```
printf -v nameArg '%q' "$nameArg"
```

Comment: With this solution if someone calls your script with the argument ?.txt it'll find all files whose names are one character followed by .txt. You probably need a solution that will handle all metacharacters not just *. Also what if someone calls your script with the argument `\*.txt` (as you'd expect and knoweldgable user to do)? If you throw in another backslash then your find will be looking for files that start with a backslash and then have any characters and end in ".txt".

Comment: Interesting - I've never heard of `%q` and can't find it in any clear definition of it in any man page. Does it escape shell globbing characters or BRE or ERE metacharacters or what?

Comment: It's one of the extra formats in bash's printf - seems to be widely available. It appears to quote only things that would be problematic in unquoted strings (spaces, file metacharacters, etc.). It ignores '.'s, for example, so it's not dealing with regexs. It's not a replacement for Perl's quotemeta, but it is useful. (Also escapes embedded newlines I just discovered.)

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the `*` in your input. If you write your script to escape them for you, you lose the ability to provide input that contains `*` as both a literal character and a metacharacter. As an example, how would you provide the pattern `\*.*` (name is `*`, with an arbitrary extension) to an auto-quoting script?

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r nameArg
find . -name "$nameArg"
```

Then on the command line:

```
$ bash myscript.sh
> \*.txt
```

Comment: The script and find command in it is more complex, I'm aware I loose this ability, however it's a part of project in which I really need * to be as *. Ty for response.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you need something like this to fully solve your problem:

```
nameArg="$1"
find -print0 |
xargs -0 -L 1 awk -v n="$nameArg" 'BEGIN{f=ARGV[1]; sub(/.*\//,"",f); if (f==n"") print ARGV[1]; exit}' 2>/dev/null
```

i.e. find all files first and then select only those whose names satisfy a **string** comparison against your target string.

AFAIK there is no way to tell `find` so search for strings rather than patterns and there is no way to reliably escape the shell globbing characters in the `find` search pattern.